# https://repo.spring.io/snapshot doesn't contain the latest snapshot for Spring Cloud Netflix

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Where can I find the latest **snapshots** of **Spring Cloud Netflix**?

Spring Initializr uses https://repo.spring.io/snapshot which only has a snapshot as of April 7 for e.g. `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` :-(

Comment: Those are the latest that built with boot 2.0. We're in the middle of getting it compatible. Why are you using the 2.0 snapshots.

Comment: I wanted to give **Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1** a try, and my microservices are using **Spring Cloud Netflix** and **Spring Cloud Config**. Therefore, I thought that I should also use `Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` instead of `Dalston.RELEASE`.

Comment: That would be correct, but it's broken at the moment. Finchley will have a milestone in the next few weeks